# Does the Java serialVersionUID must be static? Can it be an instance variable set by a sub class through constructor?

Tags: java

Java serialVersionUID must be static? Can it be an instance variable set by a sub class through constructor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [`Serializable` docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/Serializable.html).

> A serializable class can declare its own `serialVersionUID` explicitly by declaring a field named "serialVersionUID" that must be static, final, and of type long.

So it must be static.